# How to create computed signal from signal and observable?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

Imagine standard situation in Angular:
You need to fetch data from server for some entity ID. Entity Id is a Signal and you want the fetched data to be signal too.

Something like this feels natural:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <code>{{roles()}}</code>
  `,
})
export class App {
  userId: Signal<string> = signal('userA');
  roles = computed(() => toSignal(getRoles(this.userId())));
}

//this could be api service sending  http request
const getRoles = (userId: string) => {
  return userId === 'userA' ? of([1, 2, 3]) : of([1]);
};
```

but there is a runtime errror in browser console:

```
Error: NG0203: toSignal() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-admqds?file=src/main.ts)

UPDATE: I also tried to provide Injector into `toSignal`:

```
 constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  userId: Signal<string> = signal('userA');
  roles = computed(() =>
    toSignal(getRoles(this.userId()), { injector: this.injector })()
  );
```

but then another runtime error:

```
Error: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an `effect` by default. Use `allowSignalWrites` in the `CreateEffectOptions` to enable this inside effects.
```

Comment: The second error is misleading since there is no `allowSignalWrites` option for `computed()` method. I checked the source code, but I couldn't find anything suspicious. You should create a GitHub issue for this since it's a really common use case. Also, this is still in the Developer Preview so these issues are expected I guess.

Comment: I see you have posted this issue on the repo : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50192

Comment: Even if this worked as you'd planned you'd end up with `Signal<Signal<Roles[]>>` and then have to dereference it twice `roles()()`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for **effect**, as what you want can be accomplished with the rxjs interop functions.

For the *roles* signal, the *userId* has to be converted to an observable with **toObservable**.  Then value of this new observable is piped to a **switchMap** operator to get the *roles* value from a service.  Finally, the inner observable stream is converted back to a signal by passing it to **toSignal**.

```
export class App {
  readonly userId = signal('userA');

  readonly roles = toSignal(toObservable(this.userId).pipe(
    switchMap(userId => getRoles(userId)),
  ), { initialValue: [] });
}
```

In the example above, an initial value is provided.  You can omit that, but that will create an initial undefined emission.

Answer (score 2):

How about something more like this:

```
export class App {
  userId = signal('userA');
  roles = signal<number[]>([]);

  roleEffect = effect(() =>
    this.getRoles(this.userId()).subscribe(
       r = this.roles.set(r)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: If there would be more signals in this class would this effect be run on all signals changes - so `getRoles` would be fired every time?

Comment: The effect always gets the *current* value of its signals. So if several signals change before the effect is run, it will only run one time using the current value of all signals.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, you have to handle the signal as any async value :

```
roles = computed(() =>
  getRoles(this.userId())
);
```

And call the async pipe :

```
{{roles() | async }
```

What do you think about it ?

---

Edit: About the 2nd error message, you're writing a signal by creating it with `toSignal()` which also subscribes and sets the new values. (See [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe08be96633171567e30eb91dd1d23c60a2952/packages/core/rxjs-interop/src/to_signal.ts#L168-L181))

Comment: well, interesting idea. In that case I guess I'd prefer to have effect that will create an observable and assign it to class propery. Sounds simpler.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the kind of use cases effect is for.

Comment: You don't really get any benefits from using Signals at all with this way. Also it wouldn't initiate the http call until the template tried to display the value - which seems wrong.